# How can I convert HTML/CSS to PDF using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, canvas

I have looked at jsPDF but the plugin strips CSS in the exported PDF. I have looked at html2canvas also, but that takes a screenshot of the current window. My HTML content is hidden from the user and I am looking for a solution that would create a PDF on the fly from a HTML block. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I just tried creating html2canvas to jsPDF but I get an empty pdf document. Can someone please tell me why? http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/6320/

```
$('.download').on('click', function(){
    html2canvas($('.print'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        $('#canvas').replaceWith(canvas);
    },
    //width: 200,
    //height: 200
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
          return true;
      }
        };

    doc.fromHTML($('canvas').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': '200',
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');

    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: There is no simple solution. You would need the implementation of half of the full web browser in JavaScript. I would generate PDF on server using this program: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ .

Answer (score 3):

Could you use html2canvas as follows, it shouldn't matter that your html content is hidden you should be able to access it like so:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
pdf.addHTML($('#hiddenElement').html(), function () {
    pdf.save('Test.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Ok, I am tried this out - a combination of html2canvas and jsPDF over here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/6320/ Any idea why the PDF returns an empty document?